# Can the Publisher/Copyright name for an Individual Apple Developer account be changed?

Tags: iphone, ios

What what I understand, when you upload your first app you set the publisher name and from then on it cannot be changed.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. Apple may help you if you ask nicely through e-mail, but there is no official possibility to do this.

You could try e-mailing Paolo Varani, he's helped us with the same issue before and it was fixed within hours.

The trick with Apple is to stay friendly and, above all, patient.
(or to just not make any mistakes at all ;) )

Comment: I was not as lucky. Could not change the publisher name. They mentioned that it may be easier to pay for a new account with a new publisher name, and move the apps over. Copyright is different from publisher name. It is tied to an app instead of an account, and you can change it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You simply cant change this name.

> "Important: You cannot edit your company’s name after submitting it on
>   this page. The settings you specified will apply to all apps added to
>   your account, so be sure they are correct before continuing. Do not
>   include Apple trademarks."

[ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH11-SW1) Apple